# Can I safely sell everything marked as “Treasure” in Resident Evil Village?

Tags: resident-evil-village

I’ve collected a few pieces of treasure from my time in RE8. Some of it, like crystal skulls, can obviously be sold to the Duke because it drops from common enemies.

On one corpse I found an item called “Ingrid’s Necklace” which seems it could be used in a puzzle later on. I’ve found other treasures that seem like they could be more than just trinkets, but I haven’t found a clear use for them in there same way that Key Items can be used.

That raises the question? Can I sell these intriguing treasures for Lei and not a risk failing a puzzle? Or should I hold on to them because the Village is a dangerous place and I never know what supplies I’ll need?

Comment: FWIW if you haven't worked it out by now Ingrid’s Necklace is not in the treasures menu but the key items. Might be worth examining it....

Comment: Are you thinking of Luiza's necklace? Ingrid's necklace is in the treasures menu

Comment: Oh Luiza's, yeah... woops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No treasures ever act as keys later on, so you can sell every treasure without locking yourself out of any puzzles.

However, some treasures marked as combinable can be combined with others for more money, so you don't always want to instantly sell every treasure.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Are there any common treasures that I should learn to combine before selling?

Comment: @PausePause On the menu that shows your treasures, treasures that can be combined have a "combinable" descriptor. Any treasure that's combinable can be combined with another treasure for more money, and all combinable treasures are unique.

Comment: Thanks! I just saw that myself!